# How to Import images from Google Drive to WooCommerce importer using image URLS in CSV

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce, import, google-drive-api

I am trying to set up a CSV file to import multiple images with product info to WooCommerce on Wordpress, however the single last problem I have is importing the images from Google Drive.

Every time I attempt to import, I receive an error message **"Invalid image: Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type."**

I have attempted with sharing link..

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11s0ced0QG1DyJ7i3kNcjKABtnbhJ0YPe/view?usp=sharing
```

I then made some changes by copying the ID from the original URL (the characters between the /d/ and /view), and use it in these URl with =view or =download.

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=11s0ced0QG1DyJ7i3kNcjKABtnbhJ0YPe

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=11s0ced0QG1DyJ7i3kNcjKABtnbhJ0YPe
```

Last attempt I removed `/view?usp=sharing` from the sharing link and used `&export=download`

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11s0ced0QG1DyJ7i3kNcjKABtnbhJ0YPe&export=download
```

Note, I am using a Pipe symbol ‘|’ to separate the URLs of the multiple images of a product. But nevertheless, very unsure how to get past this Invalid image error.

So does anybody know how to get the correct Google Drive URL format to use in CSV file for WooCommerce product import?

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid I couldn't find a solution, and it turns out I'm not going to have much success trying to import images from Google Drive links.

The CSV product importer expects image links to be direct links that end in a recognised image extension e.g. .jpg, .png, .gif, etc. Google Drive does not provide links in this manner, so this will not work.

Dropbox is pretty much the same story.

Comment: Keep in mind that "negative answers" are usually best when posted by someone else.  I'd recommend putting this additional information in an edit to the question itself personally.  That will still leave the question open in the future for someone else (or even yourself) to potentially propose a solution.  Or perhaps a solution will become available at some point in the future that doesn't exist now.